# PGI Fortran integer format

Tags: fortran

I have an input text file that contains an integer record like:

```
1
```

which is read in Fortran code as:

```
read(iunit,'(i4)') int_var
```

which works fine with Gfortran, but the same code compiled with PGI Fortran Compiler expects a field 4 characters wide (the actual record is just 1 character) and throws an error. Now I know that the format specifies the width and this may or may not be correct behavior according to the Fortran standard, but my question is - **is there a compiler option for PGI that would make it behave like Gfortran in this respect?**

This 3rd party code I'm using has a lot (hundreds or thousands) of read statements like this and input data has a lot of records with "wrong" width so both modifying the code or the input data would require significant effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is connected to `blank`. This `read` should not cause an error, unless you opened the file iunit with `pad="no"`. Default is allways `pad="yes"`, which causes the input record to be padded with blanks, if it is too short.

Are you sure, that  you use correct input files, with correct line ends? There could be problems with text file that originate in Windows and in Unix the CR could be read in the input record. In this case using the `unix2dos` utility might help. You may try to read a `character(4)` string using the `a4` edit descriptor to test for this.

Comment: Yes, it was a windows line ending issue... Should've googled the exact error message first instead of trying to find logic in it :)

Answer (score 0):

Does PGI Fortran support the open keyword blank="null"?  I think that this will change the read to the behavior that you want and minimize the modifications to the code.   blank="null" versus blank="zero" doesn't seem to make a difference in gfortran 4.7.